# How to replace shield texture with item?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-resource-packs

Is there a way to replace the shield texture with an item, for instance a steak, so it shows a steak in my offhand instead of the shield?

I'm using version 1.19.

Answer (score 1):

Well as you might know, a Resource Pack's goal is to replace textures so I guess if you create / edit one, you can replace the Shield texture by a Steak texture.
If you are talking about the shield that pops up in certain server when you right click, I guess it should be the same thing.

Take a look [here](https://texture-packs.com/resourcepack/default-pack/) to download a template of the basic Minecraft texture pack.
Shield texture is here `/assets/minecraft/textures/entity/`
As you have `shield_base_nopattern.png` and `shield_base.png`, the difference is that the no_pattern is for the shield that has no banners applied. The other one is for the shield with the banner applied, the banner substitutes the white of the shield.

Comment: Yes I've tried that, but the thing is that the model of the shield stays the same, so you can't just replace the texture or it will get cursed.

Comment: Yeah seems pretty normal as the texture is in different squared parts and the steak texture is totally different. I guess you'll have to try that by yourself, look up on YTB how to replace two different textures (not only steak and shield, might be sword and flower for ex.) or if you're lucky enough, someone might come here to tell you :v